# Problem referencing a survey report type of document

Tags: bibtex

I have an issue referencing a document in LaTeX. The correct reference would be:

> Harvest Choice, 2006. "Tanzania National Sample Census of Agriculture 2002/2003: Small Holder Agriculture, Volume II: Crop Sector - National Report." International Food Policy Research Institute, Washington, DC., and University of Minnesota, St. Paul, MN. Available online at http://harvestchoice.org/publications/tanzania-national-sample-census-agriculture-20022003-small-holder-agriculture-volume-ii.

I have tried many combinations and the best I could come up with was using the following on bibtex:

```
@TechReport{TN,
    author = {Harvest Choice},
    title = {Tanzania National Sample Census of Agriculture 2002/2003: Small Holder Agriculture, Volume 2: Crop Sector National Report},
    institution = {International Food Policy Research Institute, Washington, DC., and University of Minnesota, St. Paul, MN},
    year = {2006} 
}
```

However, this yields 3 problems:

1. It cannot get to "Harvest Choice" being referenced, I only have: "Harvest, C" as it if were an author
2. I do not know how to insert the web link.
3. The reference specifies it is a technical report, which it is not

Comment: this "causes" 3 problems. The verb "to yield" is inappropriate in this context

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue lately, so maybe this help. But as usually, this is depending on your bibliography style

1 - Use double braces  `author = {{Harvest Choice}}` to avoid the reformatting of things via bibtex

2 - I used the `url = {}` field and a latex url command within it: `url = {\url{yadayada}}`

3 - You could try other bibliography styles or edit the .bst file of the one you currently use. But first, you could try the `@Misc` bibtex entry type with the same fields, maybe it creates the desired outcome.

Comment: Note that the OP's posting contains an error -- the organization's name is "HarvestChoice" (no space), not "Harvest Choice"...

Comment: You are right, but this is not related to the LaTeX problem. GIGO ;)

Answer (score 4):

The organization HarvestChoice suggests the following citation of the publication in question:

> HarvestChoice, 2006. "[Tanzania] National Sample Census of Agriculture 2002/2003: Small Holder Agriculture, Volume II: Crop Sector - National Report." International Food Policy Research Institute, Washington, DC., and University of Minnesota, St. Paul, MN. Available online at http://harvestchoice.org/publications/tanzania-national-sample-census-agriculture-20022003-small-holder-agriculture-volume-ii.

Observe that there is *no space* between the two parts of the name of the author. Note also the square brackets around the word "Tanzania".

Translating this into a bib entry, you may want to use the catch-all `@misc` entry type:

```
@misc{hc:2006,
  author       = "HarvestChoice",
  title        = "{[Tanzania] National Sample Census of 
                  Agriculture 2002\slash 2003: Small Holder 
                  Agriculture, Volume~II: Crop Sector~-- 
                  National Report}",
  year         = 2006,
  howpublished = "International Food Policy Research Institute,
                  Washington, DC., and University of Minnesota,
                  St.~Paul, MN",
  url          = "http://harvestchoice.org/publications/tanzania-national-sample-census-agriculture-20022003-small-holder-agriculture-volume-ii",
}
```

Observe the insertion of a matched pair of curly braces around the `title` field. This prevents the words in that field from being converted to lowercase. Note also the use of `\slash` in `2002\slash 2003`; this informs LaTeX that it's permissible to insert a line break after the slash.

**Update, June 2019**: Within the past year or so, the `xurl` package has been released. This package allows arbitrary line breaks in URL strings and is thus more flexible (typographically speaking) than the older `url` package.

Assuming that you're using the `plainnat` bibliography style and the packages `natbib`, `xurl`, and `hyperref`, you might get the following MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{hc:2006,
  author       = "HarvestChoice",
  title        = "{[Tanzania] National Sample Census of 
                  Agriculture 2002\slash 2003: Small Holder 
                  Agriculture, Volume~II: Crop Sector~-- 
                  National Report}",
  year         = 2006,
  howpublished = "International Food Policy Research Institute,
                  Washington, DC., and University of Minnesota,
                  St.~Paul, MN",
  url          = "http://harvestchoice.org/publications/tanzania-national-sample-census-agriculture-20022003-small-holder-agriculture-volume-ii",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{xurl} % 'xurl' generalizes the 'url' package
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{hc:2006}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I tried to solve as you sugggested and it works great. And thanks for the detailed explanations, greatly appreciated